# GUI front end to execute a list of shell scripts

Tags: user-interface, unix

I have a list of Unix commands that is used to install our software. Instead of copy and pasting the commands one by one into a terminal, I would like to present the list in a GUI front end, so that the person installing it just needs to click a button next to the command to execute it.

The timestamp should be logged as well as the status (execution in progress or exited). As the list of commands changes for each installation and can be executed in parallel or in a specific order, the GUI front end should be able to reflect these changes easily.

Is there an existing tool that already provides such a front end given a list of Unix commands? If not, which tool do you recommend to use to develop such a front end?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like [Zenity](http://www.susegeek.com/general/zenity-display-gtk-dialog-boxes-from-command-line-and-shell-scripts/), or maybe [gtkdialog](http://dir.filewatcher.com/d/Ubuntu/sparc/interpreters/gtkdialog_0.7.9-1_sparc.deb.74576.html), if either are available on your platform and/or you can include them with the software you want to install.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was more looking for a tool to display a list of commands easily (like a webpage for example) then a button next to each command to actually execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Tcl/Tk, though a solution with Python and either Tkinter or wxPython would be equally easy if you're familiar with Python. Both those languages, as well as many other dynamic languages, make it pretty easy to do tasks like this. If you know some other dynamic language (ruby, groovy, perl, etc) there's a good chance it has a GUI toolkit you could use.